# How do I import a CA certificate into Android 4.4.2 in the emulator?

Tags: android, security, certificate

I tried both DER and PEM formats. I tried using the file extensions crt, cer, p12, pem but nothing of them get imported. I went into Settings > Security > Install from SD card and it takes me to the Downloads page. I have the certificates listed but when I click on them, nothing happens.

Updated to add: I ended up going back to 4.3. It works fine in that.

Answer (score 18):

1. Go to Android Virtual Device Manager (sdk\tools\android.bat avd)
2. Start your emulator but select 'Wipe user Data' when you're starting the emulator
3. Copy your certificate into /storage/sdcard using e.g. sdk/tools/monitor.bat
4. Set a screenlock pin here: Settings > Security > Screenlock > PIN
5. Now you can import the certificate properly via Settings > Security > Install from storage

Background: I also had the same problem you described and it seems to be an android emulator 4.4.2 bug which occurs when you don't import the certificate first thing i.e. when you don't follow the exact steps above.

Answer (score 7):

This question is old, but still persists.  Hopefully this will help some other developers who still need to add a certificate to their emulator.

Download the certificate using any of the various methods.  I emailed myself the certificate from my computer, turned on the emulator, ran gmail and downloaded the certificate to the emulator through gmail.

Depending on your settings, you may be prompted to accept the certificate as soon as its downloaded.  Others may be able to find the certificate file using a *files* program where simply executing it will install the certificate.

But for those who can't, here's the sure-fire method.

1. Run the Settings app
2. Security
3. Encryption & Credentials
4. Install a Certificate
5. choose Selected CA Certificate
6. Install anyway
7. tap on the downloaded certificate

You should get a Toast saying that the CA certificate was installed.

This is for an emulator running **Android R**.  Good luck!

Comment: It works but is slow as hell If you need to install 50 certificates U_U

Comment: @htafoya Oh man, that's gotta be miserable!  :(

Comment: You can also just drag and drop the certificate from Windows onto the emulator. It will drop the file in the SD card's download folder.

Comment: @AndrWeisR If that works it's great!  But I've found it's not reliable.  Wish I knew what makes it work and what makes it not work (I'm on mac).

Answer (score 2):

With your limited description, I'll try to help as much as I can.

Ensure your problematic AVD (4.4 I assume) has available storage space. Try best to ensure it is a clean AVD with nothing extra installed.

Place your cert in the root /sdcard/ and install at:
Settings -> Security -> Install from SD card

Avoid installation of certs with the same name but different formats.

Comment: try this: https://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/2011/08/setting-up-a-persistent-trusted-ca-in-an-android-emulator/

Answer (score 2):

Problem with *.p12 files (pkcs12):

at: Settings -> Security -> Install from SD card the *.p12 files are grayed out. When I download the file via webserver and try to open it, android say me "Can't open" Same with *.pem files.
I tried it with 4.4.2 and 4.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

There is a script available at  https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/204#issuecomment-32837093.

Comment: I'll try the script. I tried that manually but it didn't help but I'll try again.