# Fetch request fails in react-native for https and not http in android

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux

The following is the code that i have used to make a fetch request. I seem to be facing an issue only with https request and not http in android. I am using Android studio with an emulator to develop the code.

```
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log("Success");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
      });
```

The response I get is as follows;

```
 D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:73 TypeError: Network request failed
        at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:441)
        at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172)
        at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\react-

native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:569)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:399)
    at D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:505
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:353)
    at D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:118
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:316)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (D:\RNApp\newtest\TheTestApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:117)
```

I am currently using react-native v0.53.3 . I have been searching for a solution to this problem for quite some time. If someone can please help me it would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the time in the emulator set correctly? This is important to verify the certificate.

Comment: Yes, the time is set to my system time.

Comment: I was concerned if it was a network issue with company that i work for, but i guess its safe to say its not because http seems to work ok. Also, when i try and implement a email and password login using google's firebase i seem to be facing a "auth/network-request-failed" issue which i am pretty much guessing is the same as the issue shown above.

Answer (score 2):

After much research and brain wrecking, i found out that the problem was pretty simple. The network that I use has a proxy server that encrypts all SSL traffic. So the solution was to install the associated certificates into the emulator.

So from my desktop browser which is connected to the same network, i downloaded all the certificates associated with that proxy server and imported it into the SD card (storage) of my emulator. This import and installation can be done by following the steps mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206920/how-do-i-import-a-ca-certificate-into-android-4-4-2-in-the-emulator) post.

Once this was done, i re-ran the above code and i found that the response was coming through successfully. Hope this will help anyone who is stuck in the same situation as mine.