# Request to my backend failed

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to resolve problem with sending data to my backend from my device (android 4.4.2), but it's throws an exception:

```
307 22408-22468/ru.scapegoats.checkers E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x648bfce0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x649de940 arg=0x0
06-15 20:43:02.307 22408-22468/ru.scapegoats.checkers E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x648bfce0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
06-15 20:43:02.352 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers E/dd: why
06-15 20:43:02.352 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
06-15 20:43:02.355 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:409)
06-15 20:43:02.355 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)
06-15 20:43:02.355 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:270)
06-15 20:43:02.355 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
06-15 20:43:02.355 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
06-15 20:43:02.355 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
06-15 20:43:02.355 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
06-15 20:43:02.355 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
06-15 20:43:02.356 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
06-15 20:43:02.356 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
06-15 20:43:02.356 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
06-15 20:43:02.356 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
06-15 20:43:02.356 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
06-15 20:43:02.357 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
06-15 20:43:02.357 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
06-15 20:43:02.357 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
06-15 20:43:02.357 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
06-15 20:43:02.358 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
06-15 20:43:02.358 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:212)
06-15 20:43:02.358 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
06-15 20:43:02.358 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
06-15 20:43:02.358 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
06-15 20:43:02.358 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
06-15 20:43:02.359 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
06-15 20:43:02.359 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-15 20:43:02.359 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-15 20:43:02.359 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-15 20:43:02.359 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
06-15 20:43:02.364 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:282)
06-15 20:43:02.365 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)
06-15 20:43:02.365 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:611)
06-15 20:43:02.365 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
06-15 20:43:02.365 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
06-15 20:43:02.365 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     ... 26 more
06-15 20:43:02.366 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
06-15 20:43:02.368 22408-22408/ru.scapegoats.checkers W/System.err:     ... 31 more
```

But when I run my app on emulator (android 7.0) it's works fine...
I'm using retrofit v2 for request:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
CLIENT = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                    .build();

gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();
return new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(mysite)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(CLIENT).build();
```

Comment: your server's ssl certificate is not being accepted by your device

Comment: what should I do then?

Comment: get one that works or try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206920/how-do-i-import-a-ca-certificate-into-android-4-4-2-in-the-emulator  with your current one